# Axis fault : faultString: java.io.IOException for suitetalk

Tags: lotus-notes, apache-axis, webservice-client, netsuite

I am trying to use NetSuite's  suiteTalk java api for writing an interface between our lotus notes system and NetSuite.
The first error thrown by the code was a class def not found error.
for :

```
sun/security.provider/sun.class
sun/security.provider/sun$1.class
sun/security.provider/NativePRNG.class
```

I figured out that rt.jar in lotus notes was actually missing this files. So I added these class files from the jdk1.6 i had downloaded separately. Once I fixed that I started getting axis.Faults error.

Here is the simple login code that I am trying to execute from lotus note agent:

```
   public void loginTest(){

         NetSuitePortType _port=null;
        // In order to use SSL forwarding for SOAP message. Refer to FAQ for details
        System.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory","org.apache.axis.components.net.SunFakeTrustSocketFactory");


        // Locate the NetSuite web service
        NetSuiteServiceLocator serviceLocator= new NetSuiteServiceLocator();

        //Get the service port
        try {
            _port=serviceLocator.getNetSuitePort();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in intializing GlobalSuiteTalkSetup");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Setting client timeout to 2 hours for long running operatotions
        ((NetSuiteBindingStub) _port).setTimeout(60*60*1000*2);
        try {
        // Populate Passport object with all login information
           Passport passport = new Passport();
           RecordRef role = new RecordRef();
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


           passport.setEmail("username");
           passport.setPassword("password.");
           role.setInternalId("3");
           passport.setRole(role);
           passport.setAccount("111111");


           // Login to NetSuite
           System.out.print("\nLogging into NetSuite");
           System.out.print("  Username: " + passport.getEmail());
           System.out.print("  Account: " + passport.getAccount());
           System.out.print("  password: " + passport.getPassword());
           System.out.print("  role: " + passport.getRole());

           Status status;

            status = (_port.login(passport)).getStatus();

           // Process the response
           if (status.isIsSuccess() == true) 
           {

            System.out.print("\nThe login was successful and a new session has been created.");
           } else 
           {
            // Should never get here since any problems with the
            // login should have resulted in a SOAP fault
            System.out.print("Login failed");
            //System.out.print(getStatusDetails(status));
           }


    } catch (InvalidVersionFault e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();


    } catch (InvalidCredentialsFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InsufficientPermissionFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExceededRequestLimitFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnexpectedErrorFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAccountFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Error thrown by code:

```
AxisFault


faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.io.IOException
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.io.IOException
at org.apache.axis.components.net.SunJSSESocketFactory.initFactory(SunJSSESocketFactory.java:88)
at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:79)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at com.netsuite.webservices.platform_2015_1.NetSuiteBindingStub.login(NetSuiteBindingStub.java:12799)
at Login.loginTest(Unknown Source)
at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)

{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:

java.io.IOException
at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at com.netsuite.webservices.platform_2015_1.NetSuiteBindingStub.login(NetSuiteBindingStub.java:12799)
at Login.loginTest(Unknown Source)
at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.apache.axis.components.net.SunJSSESocketFactory.initFactory(SunJSSESocketFactory.java:88)
at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:79)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
... 14 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this issue. For anyone who might get similar issue can get some clue from this solution :

The issue was because of the following statement that I had put in the code.

```
System.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory","org.apache.axis.components.net.SunFakeTrustSocketFactory");
```

This statement is necessary when using Sun' JVM but since Lotus Notes uses IBM's JVM, setting axis.socketSecureFactory to org.apache.axis.components.net.SunFakeTrustSocketFactory made the system to look for Sun classes which not absent in IBM's JVM.

No need to add the missing classes from Sun JVM to rt.jat as I had done before. Just comment that statement and  use the axis path available frpm [NetSuite](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-sample-applications.shtml)

Don't forget to put the patch in Note's /JVM/Lib/EXT folder and restart Lotus Notes before trying to run the code..